# If I'm using a voice or video call on Facebook, does it show me as "active now" or offline?

Tags: facebook-messenger

Was wondering if while I'm using voice or video chat on Facebook, what is my online or offline status?

Answer (score 1):

Status would be online. Once you login Facebook or messenger (for chat, video or voice call), it shows online if you have not customise your setting for chat.

And you can continue using chat and other Facebook features during your video call, but you can only call one friend at a time.

Answer (score -1):

Well it depends...sometimes if you're in a call long enough it will show active 28 minutes, etc., or depending how long you have been in the call it will eventually show you as offline.